# React - class method syntax

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic React question. Can you tell me what is the difference between the two **onDismiss** methods?

```
class App extends Component {

constructor (props){
super(props)
this.state = {..}
}

onDismiss (id){ ... }

onDismiss = (id) =>{ ... }


render(){...}
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: The first doesn't have `this` from the class bound to it, but the second one does, being an arrow function. This is a javascript syntax, unrelated to React, BTW.

Comment: Drew Reese, correct me if I am wrong. So, you are saying that the first one doesn't need a `this.onDismiss = this.onDismiss.bind(this)` in the constructor but the second one does?

Comment: Other way around. The first one needs to be bound in the constructor, the second one doesn't.

Comment: Fantastic, now it makes sense. Thank you!!